# Create a policy exemption where the scope is a resource (Azure & Terraform)

Tags: azure, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

Can you create a policy exemption where the scope is a resource (not RG) in Azure with Terraform?
cause I found this module:

```
  module "policy_exemptions" {
  source  = "globalbao/policy-exemptions/azurerm"
  version = "0.2.1"
  policyExemptions = {
    exemption1 = {
      deploymentMode     = "Incremental"
      name               = "exemption1"
      displayName        = "exemption1 for Insert-Your-RG-Name1"
      description        = "exemption1 waives compliance on an resource group"
      resourceGroupName  = "Insert-Your-RG-Name1"
      policyAssignmentId = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/production/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/2f97de7d41f348529e23d8ae"
      policyDefinitionReferenceIds = []
      exemptionCategory = "Waiver"
      expiresOn         = "2025-12-29"
      metadata = {}
    }
  }
}
```

But You can only put the RGs name not the resource...
Maybe I don't understand the syntax?

Comment: You can use the exported resource attribute of a resource as a value to the argument: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html#references-to-resource-attributes. We would need more specific information to assist further.

Comment: Hello @NoaHochman, The module you are using has a ARM template which sets policy exemptions as there is no direct resource to create policy exemptions from terraform. The ARM template is missing a scope , if you define that then you can restrict its usage to the a particular resource in the resource group. but for now its being applied to all the resources present in the resource group.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in the comments, the Policy exemptions module doesn't have a scope mentioned so it gets applied to the resource group.

As a Solution you will have to change few thing in the module file after you have initialized terraform.

**Step 1 :** Go to the `Module>>policy_exemptions>>policyExemption.json` . Add Scope in parameter and in resources as shown below:

[image]

**Step 2 :** Go to `Module>>policy_exemptions>>variables.tf` . Add Scope in the variable as shown below:

[image]

**Step 3 :** Go to `Module>>policy_exemptions>>main.tf`. Add scope in the `resource_group_deployment` block in the `parameters_content` as shown below:

[image]

**Step 4 :** Then you can the module like below:

```
  provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
  }
  module "policy_exemptions" {
  source  = "globalbao/policy-exemptions/azurerm"
  version = "0.2.1"
  policyExemptions = {
    exemption1 = {
      deploymentMode     = "Incremental"
      name               = "exemption1"
      displayName        = "exemption1 for cloudshell storage acocunt"
      description        = "exemption1 waives compliance on an resource group"
      resourceGroupName  = "ansuman-resourcegroup"
      policyAssignmentId = "/subscriptions/88xxxxb30-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxc93573ae/resourceGroups/ansuman-resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/b3f5ccb5b1a74a2db0401c0e"
      policyDefinitionReferenceIds = []
      exemptionCategory = "Waiver"
      expiresOn         = "2025-12-29"
      scope             = "/subscriptions/88xxxxb30-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxc93573ae/resourceGroups/ansuman-resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/cloudshellansuman123"
      metadata = {}
    }
  }
}
```

---

I tested the modified module to add a exemption to the policy `Storage account keys should not be expired` on a specific resource that is a Storage account .

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can find the Modified code after the commits I have made in my [Github Repo](https://github.com/AnsumanBal-MT/terraform-azurerm-policy-exemptions). You can check the below three commits:

- Update main.tf …
- Update variables.tf …
- Update policyExemptions.json